# What happens when you enter a clan war with a building that is currently being built?

Tags: clash-of-clans

What happens if you're in a clan war and you've just started building a completely new building.
E.g. you upgrade town hall and you input a new Wizard tower. While the wizard tower is still being built in your normal base, is the tower still available for use in clan war or something different?

Answer (score 2):

The building shows up as "still being built". If it is a defense it does nothing.